# Avahi / Zeroconf: Configure DNS-SD for external Server

Tags: network-printer, avahi, bonjour

I have a centralized remote printer, say "printer.company.com" with IPP and I need to publish this printer in a local network with NAT.

Services for "local" services are no problem, but I could not find any easy to follow solution to configure AVAHI-Deamon etc. to publish a service for another Host.

Is there a way to do this? If yes, how?

I only need Zeroconf for one printer in a BYOD scenario, so that not every user has to set up the printer by themselfs.

Comment: Don't. Set up a proper DNS infrastructure once you reach the threshold of having multiple subnets and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @vidarlo, I only need an easy way for users of a BYOD set up to use the shared printer, without the need for every user to configure it by themself. Zeroconf seems to be the easiest and most versatile solution for this project.

Comment: These are layer 2 protocols, so you can't.

Comment: Zeroconf, mDNS are based on UDP (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) How is that a layer 2 protocol?
IPP is based on TCP, also not a layer 2 protocol.

What would be your recommended alternative approach?

Comment: IPP runs over the Internet; mDNS does not. It is confined to a single layer 2 segment. UDP is irrelevant.

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to announce an remote IPP service in my local layer 2 segment.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? (Having a similar issue of trying to publish a network printer for AirPrint)